# How to apply css for pdf.cell in JSPDF

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, jspdf

I have a requirement Where I need to generate a PDF file which consists of table.
I am able to generate PDF. But, I want to apply styles to border. Currently the border is showing black in color. I want to change the color to white. Ho do I do that??

Here is my js function which is called when "Export to PDF" link is clicked.

For `tableId` I am passing my table name.

My table is as shown:

[image]

My PDF Generated is as shown:

[image]

I want to change the border color of my generate PDF to "grey". How am I supposed to do that? Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before calling `cell()` method you have to set `drawColor` property.

To set draw color use `setDrawColor` method

`setDrawColor(R,G,B);`

More details about this method are here in the API documentation.
http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/global.html#setDrawColor

The draw color can be reset to **black** by setting the RGB value to 
 `setDrawColor(0);`

Example:

```
  //Set text color
  doc.setTextColor(0);
  doc.text(10, 10, 'This is a test');

  //Change text color
  doc.setTextColor("#42d254");
  //Set draw color
  doc.setDrawColor(150,150,150);
  doc.cell(40, 40, 50, 20, "cell"); //cell(x,y,w,h,text,i)
```

Check this fiddle for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/Purushoth/x4xo4owj/

**Please checkout [jsPDF-Autotable](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable) plugin which has lot of built-in features for custom styling https://simonbengtsson.github.io/jsPDF-AutoTable/#header-footer.**