# Streaming Updates from websocket api with redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, websocket, stream, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am new to redux-toolkit query and also new to websocket APIs, and I am trying to get a stream of data from a websocket API and store it in a redux store.

I have read the documentation for createApi and useQuery, but I am still having difficulty understanding [this part](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/streaming-updates).

Here is the message structure that the websocket API gets:

```
{
"message_type": "xxx",
"payload": {
    "event_id": "sr:match:xxxxxx"
}
```

}

is this code should do the work?

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query";

export const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "/" }),
  reducerPath: "api",
  tagTypes: ["Message"],
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    streamMessages: build.query({
      queryFn: () => ({ data: [] }),
      async onCacheEntryAdded(arg, { updateCachedData, cacheEntryRemoved }) {
        const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/ws");
        ws.addEventListener("open", () => {
          ws.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
            updateCachedData((draft) => {
              draft.push(event);
            });
          });
        });

        await cacheEntryRemoved;
        ws.close();
      },
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useStreamMessagesQuery } = api;
```

and if it is, how can i use it? when i try using useStreamMessagesQuery in some components its undefined and not a function.
Thank you.

Comment: [this part of that page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42665189/how-to-apply-css-for-pdf-cell-in-jspdf) specifically addresses your question. Find this text and review the source code there: "_For example, the data is transformed from this shape:_"

Comment: It appears you might be refering to adapters: [look here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en)

Comment: @RandyCasburn im sorry but i don't understand what this links have to do with my question

Comment: You've updated your question, so no, I'm not sure you are attempting to transform the data.